# Can a power of attorney allow you to act "pro se" on behalf of the issuer?

Tags: unlicensed-practice, pro-se, power-of-attorney

Anyone can represent themselves in a court of law, if he or she doesn't want, or can't afford, a lawyer. On the other hand, only lawyers who have passed the bar in a state are allowed to represent others.

Suppose you have an aging parent (or other relative) that is certifiably "incompetent" but has given you the power of attorney. From the sound of it, this means that you would be able to represent this person "pro se" or through other means.

Is this true? Or is it a case where "power of attorney" doesn't confer the right to act as a lawyer for someone who is incompetent, even though it sounds like it does (to a layman).

Are there at least some forums, such as small claims court, where the "power of attorney" gives you the right to act as someone's "lawyer?"

Comment: Possible duplicate, or at least [appears to be answered here](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/6748/10).

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close given the similarity to Cicero's question, but this question is both more general (not simply criminal) and better framed

Comment: For example, can a person represent Mom who is incapacitated in small claims court where attorneys are generally prohibited.

Comment: @feetwet: No longer a duplicate. The other question was about "criminal." Mine was "general" including civil forums such as small claims court?

Comment: A related question: even if the person with power of attorney (sometimes called an attorney-in-fact) can't represent the principal in court, would they be able to hire a lawyer to act on the principal's behalf?

Comment: A person can only act *pro se* for him- or herself. That's what the term means, after all.

Comment: @NateEldredge Someone with a power of attorney can hire a lawyer to act on a principal's behalf assuming that this is within the scope of the grant of authority in the POA.

Answer (score 4):

For most civil matters the answer is "no". Small claims court is special since there are restrictions on using attorneys, and in that context, it depends on the rules. In [Indiana](http://www.in.gov/judiciary/files/small-claims-manual.pdf), the answer in their manual is no

> [Small Claims Rule 8](http://www.in.gov/judiciary/rules/small_claims/#_Toc414969481) allows a person to appear at trial and, if he or
>   she chooses, represent himself or herself and avoid the cost of hiring
>   an attorney. However, a person is allowed to hire an attorney and have
>   the attorney appear with him or her at the trial. A person who has
>   power of attorney for another person may not represent that person in
>   court.

"Have the attorney appear with him or her at the trial" is pretty unclear, since it doesn't say whether the attorney can *represent* them. Rule 8(C)(1) states that "A natural person may appear pro se or by counsel in any small claims proceeding", which clarifies that they don't just mean "have at your side". In [Minnesota](http://www.mncourts.gov/mncourtsgov/media/PublicForms/Conciliation%20-%20Small%20Claims%20Court/CCT101_Information-about-Conciliation-Court.pdf), the answer is more emphatic "no":

> **A power of attorney does not authorize a nonlawyer to file a claim, appear, or in any other way “represent” a natural person in 
>   conciliation court.**

As for allowing attorneys in small claims court,

> Attorneys are only allowed to represent parties in conciliation court
>   *with permission of the court*

(emphasis added). The situation in California is somewhat of a hybrid, but as I read it, it means that the incapacitated person is out of luck, which strikes me as surprising. [They say](http://www.dca.ca.gov/publications/small_claims/small_claims.pdf)

> Self-representation is usually required. There are, however, several
>   exceptions to this general rule: If the court determines that a party
>   is unable to properly present his or her claim or defense for any
>   reason, the court may allow another individual to assist that party.
>   The individual who helps you  can only provide assistance—the
>   individual’s participation in court cannot amount to legal
>   representation, and the person can’t be an attorney.

So this is most unlike Indiana is that you can't have an attorney, and all the person can do is "assist". So unless they just waive the rules, this means that if the individual is incapacitated, they cannot have recourse to small claims court.

Comment: This would generally be true in most U.S. jurisdictions usually as part of unauthorized practice of law rules promulgated by a state supreme court. A few jurisdictions allow officers of companies to represent the companies in small claims court and/or administrative proceedings like unemployment hearings, but I am not aware of cases where someone with a POA can do so. The U.K. has something similar to the California rule, but that is very much the exception in U.S. law.

Comment: The British equivalent is called a McKenzie Friend. http://courtwithoutalawyer.co.uk/mckenzie%20friends%20practice%20guidance%202010.pdf